# Unique homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

Given two groups, how do you show that a homomorphism with some property is unique? I am thinking that you take two homomorphisms with that property and show they take an arbitrary element in the domain to the same element in the codomain. Is that the right way to think about it, or is there more that I should consider?

Specifically:

If $H$ is any group with $h$ an element of $H$, $h^n = 1$, and $\mathbb Z_n$ the cyclic subgroup of order $n$, show there is a unique homomorphism with the property that $x$ is mapped to $h$.

Comment: What kind of properties are you talking about in particular? AFAIK a group homomorphism is completely determined by its kernel. Any property that interacted with this would make two homomorphisms distinct...

Comment: I'll edit the question to be more specific

Comment: @Michael: that is very much not true. The kernel can at best detect the isomorphism class of the image of the homomorphism, and in particular says nothing about how the image sits in the codomain.

Comment: So it would be enough to show their kernels are isomorphic?

Comment: I'm unclear on this in particular: how to show two homomorphisms are the same.

Comment: Or how to show a homomorphism is unique

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thank you for the correction

Comment: @alpha: two homomorphisms $f_1, f_2 : G \to H$ from a group $G$ to a group $H$ are literally the same if and only if $f_1(g) = f_2(g)$ for all $g \in G$. It's a good exercise to show that it suffices to check this condition on a set of generators of $G$.

Comment: In general, if you want to show that two homomorphisms are the same, you usually show that they agree on generators.

In your case, you have a homomorphism from a cyclic group to another group, so the homomorphism is trivially unique, because the image of the generator is required to be $h$. The essential part of your exercise is to show that such a homomorphism exists.

Comment: "$x$ is mapped to $h$" but you haven't told us what you mean by $x$.

Answer (score 3):

As has been discussed in the comments, any homomorphism is fully determined by its action on generators. That is, the only possible homomorphism with $f(x)=h$ is $f(x^i)=h^i$, $f(1)=1$, as follows from the homomorphism property (and induction.) So uniqueness is settled: you have only to show this homomorphism exists.

We have defined a function mapping $1$ to $1$, so we only need to confirm that $f(x^ix^j)=f(x^{i+j})$. The possible problem is that $f(x^{i+j})$ may have been defined as $h^{i+j-n}$: in fact, this happens whenever $i+j\geq n$. So the only real point to check in our proof is that $h^ih^j=h^{i+j-n}$. But $h^{i+j-n}=h^ih^jh^{-n}$, and $h^{-n}=(h^n)^{-1}=e$.